# PHP Curl Print Problem

Tags: php

I'm trying to print an external site's HTML using curl, but when I go to **print** the html I just get a bunch of bad characters:

```
D\ÓLþ¢GÎ–´ï!ñ{HÑ,Jþ»H¹§L+÷53j?‰²î¡<‘*tÜe÷uÖbÃ¬ê~Æô¬²c˜‹§ ~áäÆL#f?â¶ŠªþU™á˜ÉÉOæ{^¤ëaÀ Tê"1Û¨Dtî’œxˆk‘:@ŽD5î:'¶e\*³q‘×¸`…±¾ôäó÷ð1j7þä‘åQ6®9bcxã„A2ã—-ÇøüåÉò÷2{ÂÐeæ¡¢Ç™ŒÄg©Az!Ø¡>Â±z×šÂ+;f RZÛÝ€ížáÒžHa¬¢Æ'ë•ñ þ=Ð=ºtyšÖâå'ÇpžÄ¦ÆN½€5½roåðFe¹)ˆš`ØnhŠy(GÆÔ} Bu7H¥JzÐ iVê÷áÆ”øG>6HÿUµÞhµj YH-ÌaaEÚx±‰…Êâ£-ûeÎqCÆLÌåã˜Ž‰†LÐÆM I]€a)Ï.$—ÅH••£ ŒŒ’ªÉ;cŽc(i´¥!I]‹€„³tFc^ë'€e±øÉ_øß
```

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.thesite.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print $result;
```

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: So what URL are you requesting? Have you tried requesting it in the browser with a blank user agent? What do you get?

Comment: The url isn't important because it will be changed often, I'm just looking to grab all the HTML in the document I point the curl to.

Comment: Do you get headers back?  Check out the Content-Encoding header.   the body may be compressed.  If you're not even getting headers back, are you sure you're connecting to an HTTP server?

Comment: Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response is GZIP'd, you may use this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

To see if it's gzip'd, check the headers (see `CURLOPT_HEADER`).